# Select the default window to be opened at startup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a MacOS X (Objective-C / Cocoa) application which basically works this way :
first a window is opened, requesting user's username / password. If credentials are valid, the main application is displayed.

This is what I do to open my credential window :

```
@implementation BetaseriesDesktopAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    authWindow = [[AuthenticateWindow alloc] init];
    [authWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [authWindow becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)login:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Login");
    User *user = [[User alloc] init];

}

@end
```

Problem is, the main window if opened too at application startup. How can it prevent it to do so? Is it a property I must set in Interface Builder or do I have to do that in my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, select the window. In the Window Attributes info pane, deselect the option "Visible At Launch".